# What is causing my error? I am trying to create a player class and store a players name as a variable

Tags: c++, string, class, visual-c++, build-error

another noob here, so I hope someone with a bit of sense can help me! As my question states, I am simply trying to create a player class (it is for an RPG game). However, I have tried multiple ways of doing this, with the code shown being the latest, however I keep coming across different errors. I am using Microsoft visual c++ 2010 express and the error that I am currently facing is:

> 1>player.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private:
>   static class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >
>   Player::m_playerName"
>   (?m_playerName@Player@@0V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)

I hope this is enough detail! The rest of the code/files I have created are as follows:

game.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;



int main() 
{

    Player main;


   main.setStats(); 
   main.showStats();


    int stopper;
   cin >> stopper;

    return 0;



}
```

player.h

```
#include <string>

class Player
    {
    public:

        Player();
        void showStats();
        void setStats();        


    private: 

         int m_playerLVL;
         static std::string m_playerName;
    };
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

Player::Player()
{
    cout << "Please enter your name: ";
    string playerName;
    getline (cin, playerName);
    m_playerName = playerName;
}

    void Player::showStats()
    {
        cout << "Hello, i am " << m_playerName << "and i am lvl " << m_playerLVL; 
    }

    void Player::setStats()
    {
        m_playerLVL = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the name of the player to be `static`:

```
static std::string m_playerName; // DON'T MAKE IT STATIC!
```

That's semantically incorrect, and removing `static` happens to solve your problem. Each instance of `Player` should associate a different value to `m_playerName` (because each player has their own name). Declaring a data member `static` makes it global for the whole `Player` class (i.e. it is not given a per-instance value, but one global value which is the same for all `Player` objects). That doesn't sound like something you would want.

---

Now if for any reason you *really* meant to declare this as a `static` data member, then you should provide a *definition* for it at the global namespace scope:

```
std::string Player::m_playerName;
```

The linker is complaining about the lack of such a definition.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's silly but you have ended a morning of chasing code for me! :)

Comment: @Iskardes: We've all been there, glad I could help. If this solves your problem, please consider marking the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I certainly will and I am sorry it seems I haven't, I don't know whether it's because I have just created and account but for some reason there has seems to be a 15 minute delay on accepting an answer! (This might be a silly comment, but I am new to these parts >.< )

Comment: @Iskardes: No worries, that's fine :)